# Клик по кнопке — замена переменной в функции

Tags: c#

Есть, например, переменные:

```
double t2, t5, t6, t7, t8 = 1000.0, t9 = 1000.0, t10 = 100.0, t11 = 500.0;
```

Пример замены:

Исходная функция:

```
t6 = (t2 / t8);
```

После нажатия кнопки:

```
t6 = (t2 / t10);
```

В коде закомментировал место, где должна происходить подмена:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int t1, t3, t4;
    double t2, t5, t6, t7, t8 = 1000.0, t9 = 1000.0, t10 = 100.0, t11 = 500.0;
    t1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); 
    t2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
    t3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text); 
    t4 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
    t5 = (t1 / t9); 
    t6 = (t2 / t8); // t8 переменная которую нужно заменить на t10
    t7 = (t5 + t6);  
    textBox5.Text = string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3}Vol={4}_OpI={5}", t7, "clrRed", 1, 0, t3, t4); // вывод результата в пятый textbox
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку происходила замена переменной на другую в формуле и очистка «текстбоксов»?

[image: Пример программы]

Comment: @PashaPash: ладно, соглашусь. коммент удалил.

Comment: Автор, если ответ вас удовлетворяет, пожалуйста, примите его (галочка рядом с ответом)

Comment: не знал... спасибо) вроде лайкнул а тут вот система какая

Comment: голосование — для всех участников. За — ответ был вам полезен или просто верный, против — ответ ошибочный или вредный. А галочка — именно для автора вопроса. Вы ей отмечаете тот ответ, который решил **вашу** задачу.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
t5 = (t1 / t9); 
t6 = (t2 / t8); // t8 переменная которую нужно заменить на t10
t7 = (t5 + t6);
```

Дело в том, что метод объекта — вещь довольно-таки постоянная. Ее нельзя менять в ходе работы приложения (исключая вуду-магию с рефлексией).

Если следовать принципу [KISS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%29), то здесь достаточно флага и условия. Если у вас всего два варианта, то вместо `switch` сойдет и `if-else.`

```
enum Option {
    useT8,
    useT10
}

Option usedVariable = Option.useT8;

switch(usedVariable) {
case useT8:
    t6 = (t2 / t8);
    break;
case useT10:
    t6 = (t2 / t10);
    break;
...
}
```

Кстати, рекомендую немного иначе объявлять переменные:

1. Каждую в своей строке
2. Не в начале метода, а по мере необходимости, в той же строке, где присваивается первое значение.
3. Дать им осмысленные имена.

Answer (score -2):

Заменить переменные в коде не получится, можно использовать условия для того чтобы определить какую переменную использовать.

Добавить переменную `t810;` заменить строчку кода

```
t6 = (t2 / t8);
```

на

```
Change_t810();   
t6 = (t2 / t810);
```

Функция

```
private void Change_t810(){
if(t810 == t8){
  t810 = t10;
   } else {
  t810 = t8;
 }
}
```

Comment: Метод, который туда-сюда переключает переменую достаточно уязвим. Нельзя никогда точно узнать, куда он ее переключил в этот раз. Тем более, значения переменных `t8` и `t10` могут измениться, так что `t810` не будет равен ни одной из них.